# How change foreground color in a specific row from a default jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a default jtable in my application. I would like to do a little checking, and change the color of all rows that have the first column equal to close.

I've been trying to do this, and the most we got was this:

```
 String x =  jTable.getModel().getValueAt(0, 0).toString();

    if(x.equals("close")) 
 {
     jTable.setForeground(Color.red);
      }
```

But the way I did, change the color of all lines. And only makes checking the first element of the table.

I liked to do all the checking lines and change only those who had the first column equal to close.

Does anyone can help me please?

Thank all any help you can give me.

Greetings.

Comment: how about reading up on some basics about JTable, specifically about rendering? And after having done the basic reading, search this site for similar QAs, there are literally thousands of them ....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the color of a JTable entire row having a particular column value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607779/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-jtable-entire-row-having-a-particular-column-value)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I will check the link that you gave me. And sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `TableCellRenderer`. This component is like a rubber stamp that moves across the table and draws cells when it needs to - unlike a normal component in Swing which has a long life in one location.

Here's an example of one that you can use on your table.

```
class MyTableCellRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).equals("close")) {
            setForeground(Color.RED);
        } else {
            setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }
        setText(String.valueOf(value));
        return this;
    }
}

public JTableFrame() {
    JTable table = new JTable();
    // Give your table some data:
    // table.setModel(new BlahTableModel());

    // Install the renderer on all columns
    MyTableCellRenderer renderer = new MyTableCellRenderer();
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(renderer);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(renderer);


    getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, new JScrollPane(table));
}
```

Comment: typically you don't implement a TableCellRenderer from scratch (you miss all the necessary config like selected, dnd...), especially not when you implement the same mistake as DefaultXX (extend a component vs. use a component)

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement a [TableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html). Have a look at [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) of the JTabel tutorial from oracle.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
    Object value,
    boolean isSelected,
    boolean hasFocus, 
    int row, int column) 
{
 Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected,
        hasFocus, row, column);
 String str = combo.getSelectedItem().toString();
 if (value.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(str))
 {
    cell.setBackground(Color.RED);
 }
 else
 {
    cell.setBackground(null);
 }

 return cell;
}
```

Comment: better do the custom color setting _before_ calling super (to avoid the infamous color memory of DTCR)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) which is simpler than using a custom renderer because you don't need to worry about creating a custom renderer for every type of data you have in your table.

Comment: note that link-only answers ... :) And as always when you suggest your variant: subclassing JTable (or any other JSomething) for application needs is _evil_ - overriding prepareRenderer is a good solution if you have some kind of plugin mechanism that supports the configurable visual decorations.

Answer (score 0):

An example of application where you can show in red the expired rows, since date of column "Fecha Vencimiento" is before now (2021/10/10). So, the rest of the rows are showed in black.

```
private notificationContractjTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
        
private void configurarJTable() {
     JTableHeader th = notificationContractjTable.getTableHeader();
     Font fuente = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20);
     th.setFont(fuente);
     notificationContractjTable.setRowHeight(25);
     notificationContractjTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MyTableCellRenderer());
}
        
private class MyTableCellRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {
     @Override
     public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
          if (((LocalDate) table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 2)).isBefore(LocalDate.now())) {
              setForeground(Color.RED);
          } else {
              setForeground(Color.BLACK);
          }
          setText(String.valueOf(value));
          return this;
     }
}
```

[image]